# JSP Form charset mismatch

Tags: spring, jsp, utf-8

I'm using spring mvc and mysql, my problem is, when I save data using form tag of spring the encoding includes letters like "à,á,é,ã" same when I return this data from database to input fields, but when I merge with new data the encoded characters don't reach Controllers with UTF-8, the controller recives "CombustÃ£o" instead of "Combustão"

Here is my form:

```
<form action="${pageContext.request.contextPath}/catalog/carro/saveedit"
                  method="post">
                <div class="form-group">
                    <label class="col-md-4" for="nome">Carro:</label>
                    <input class="form-control" type="text" name="nome"
                           id="nome" value="${carroEditable.nome}"/>
                </div>
                <div class="form-group">
                    <label for="categoria" class="col-md-4">Categoria:</label>
                    <select name="categoria" id="categoria"
                            class="form-control">
                        <option selected value="${carroEditable.categoria}">
                            ${carroEditable.categoria}
                        </option>
                        <option value="Combustão">Combustão</option>
                        <option value="Elétrico">Elétrico</option>
                    </select>
                </div>
                <div class="form-group">
                    <button type="submit" class="btn btn-default btn-block">
                        Salvar
                    </button>
                </div>
                <input type="hidden" name="idCarro"
                       value="${carroEditable.idCarro}"/>
            </form>
```

And my Controller

```
 @RequestMapping(value = "/catalog/carro/saveedit",
            method = RequestMethod.POST)
    public String merge(ServletRequest request)
            throws ServletRequestBindingException, UnsupportedEncodingException {



        Integer id = ServletRequestUtils.getIntParameter(request, "idCarro");
        String categoria = ServletRequestUtils.getRequiredStringParameter
                (request,
                        "categoria");
        String nome = ServletRequestUtils.getRequiredStringParameter(request,
                "nome");
        Carros carros = carrosRepository.findOne(id);
        carros.setNome(nome);
        carros.setCategoria(categoria);
        carrosRepository.saveAndFlush(carros);
        return "redirect:/catalog/carro/gerencia";
```

I also tried

```
 <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8">
```

On form tag

```
content="text/html; charset=UTF-8"
```

Comment: The problem is not that you forgot to escape the string, the problem is that you escape them twice! - This kind of bug is really hard to debug (when one does not have access to the running environment). I recommend to start with the page that is rendered by the server, it must have a UTF-8 encoding (check this for example with firebug).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try adding spring's [CharacterEncodingFilter](http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/4.0.x/javadoc-api/org/springframework/web/filter/CharacterEncodingFilter.html) to your web.xml.

```
  <filter>
    <filter-name>encodingFilter</filter-name>
    <filter-class>org.springframework.web.filter.CharacterEncodingFilter</filter-class>
    <init-param>
      <param-name>encoding</param-name>
      <param-value>UTF-8</param-value>
    </init-param>
  </filter>
  <filter-mapping>
    <filter-name>encodingFilter</filter-name>
    <url-pattern>/*</url-pattern>
  </filter-mapping>
```